# What is the best way to reduce ambiguity for templated variadic functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I'm currently trying to make a variadic templated function named `MakeByte` that will take any number of arguments of bits, and put them into one byte. Here's an example of the usage for it:

```
// The Wii U has 4 RAM chips, here we select a seemingly "random" one using an
// algorithm to generate one from the coordinates.
quint32 bank_bit_0 = Bit((y / (16 * m_num_pipes)) ^ x_3);
quint32 bank_bit_1 = Bit((y / (8 * m_num_pipes)) ^ x_4);
quint32 bank = MakeByte(bank_bit_0, bank_bit_1);
```

I have three functions, in a separate header involved:

- `template <typename T1, typename... T2> T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits)`, the function that will be used by external code that calls the recursive functions.
- `template <typename T1, typename... T2> T1 MakeByte(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T1 bit, T2... bits)`, the recursive function that iterates over each bit. This function has additional arguments to keep track of the final byte, and the current position to put the next bit in.
- `template <typename T1, typename T2> T1 MakeByte(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T2 bit)`, the function that deals with the final bit.

Here's the complete 3 definitions:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T2 bit)
{
  return byte | (bit << pos);
}
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  return MakeByte(byte | (bit << pos), pos + 1, bit, bits...);
}
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  return MakeByte(static_cast<T1>(0), 0, bit, bits...);
}
```

The issue is that, when compiling with g++, I get this error:

```
/home/kyle/Documents/Projects/C++/Qt/MK8Studio/Source/Common.h:44: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
   return MakeByte(static_cast<T1>(0), 0, bit, bits...);
          ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

At this point, I renamed the two recursive functions, in case there was ambiguity:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte_(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T2 bit)
{
  return byte | (bit << pos);
}
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte_(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  return MakeByte_(byte | (bit << pos), pos + 1, bit, bits...);
}
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  return MakeByte_(static_cast<T1>(0), 0, bit, bits...);
}
```

This code does compile, but I can't help but feel this is a bit of a hack. From a design perspective, what is the best way to reduce ambiguity within variadic templated functions?

Comment: There is no universal "best way" to eliminate ambiguity. Each individual siuation gets solved by its own merits. An individual solution may involve techniques such as: renaming; using `std::enable_if`; or partially-specialized template classes invoked as workarounds for partially specialized a template function. No single size fits all.

Comment: What is`quint32`?  This matters because I doubt it is `int` which may be your problem.

Comment: @Yakk it's just a typedef for an unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's question of personal taste but I prefer to avoid to have two version of the function that are doing the same thing (in this case: shift and or).

I suggest to write the terminal case that simply return a value (no shift, no or)

```
template <typename T1>
constexpr T1 MakeByte_ (T1 byte, quint32)
{ return byte; }
```

and the recursive case

```
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte_(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T1 bit, T2... bits)
{ return MakeByte_(byte | (bit << pos), pos + 1, bit, bits...); }
```

This avoid ambiguity because if `MakeByte_` receive three or more arguments, the recursive version is called; if receive two arguments, it's called the final version.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I believe there still is ambiguity between the recursive function and the function to be used by external code.

Comment: @Koopa - haven't you solved this ambiguity naming the helper function `MakeByte_` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there are clearly different methods, as

```
quint32 bank_bit_0 = Bit((y / (16 * m_num_pipes)) ^ x_3);
quint32 bank_bit_1 = Bit((y / (8 * m_num_pipes)) ^ x_4);
quint32 bank_bit_2 = Bit((y / (m_num_pipes)) ^ x_5);

quint32 bank = MakeByte(bank_bit_0, bank_bit_1, bank_bit_1);
```

Would call your helper function

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 byte, quint32 pos, T2 bit)
```

Note: In C++17, you might even write your code:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto MakeByte_(const Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return ((std::get<Is>(tuple) << Is) | ...) ;
}
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  return MakeByteHelper(std::make_tuple(bit, bits...),
                        std::make_index_sequence<1 + sizeof...(T2)>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution thanks to `eracpp` on the Coding Den Discord server, using a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits)
{
  T1 byte = bit;
  quint32 pos = 0;
  ((byte |= ((bits & 1) << ++pos)), ...);
  return byte;
}
```

This reduces the code down to one function, but does require C++17. This takes parameters going from left to right as LSB to MSB, but this can be used to take left to right as MSB to LSB (Correlating to the binary layout):

```
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits) {
    uint32_t pos  = sizeof...(bits);
    T1      byte = bit;

    ((byte = (byte << 1) | bits), ...);

    return byte;
}
```

Finally, a non-C++17 solution they suggested that I haven't tested:

```
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr T1 MakeByte(T1 bit, T2... bits) {
    T1 byte = bit;

    using init_t = int[];
    (void)init_t{((byte = (byte << 1) | bits), 0)...};

    return byte;
}
```

Comment: your non-c++17 is C++14 (c++11 has too restrictive constraints on `constexpr` function).

Comment: The `bits` in `((byte = (byte << 1) | bits), ...);` is intentional, it's referring to the parameter pack, unless you're talking about something else.